# Shell execute don't work

Tags: ms-access, vba

This code:

```
ShellExecute("C:\Program Files\Image Eye\ImageEye.exe","*.jpg", "*.png");
```

don't work. The sub shellexecute isn't recognized. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the `ShellExecute` function on top of your module:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _ 
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _ 
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
#End If
```

You can find a full example [here](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/vbashellexecute.htm)...

Comment: I get the error:
The project code needs to be updated for use in 64-bit systems.
Review and update the instructions and then mark it with the declare attribute.  How do I change?

Comment: I've edited the answer to be compatible with 64bit... The difference is in the `PtrSafe` ...

Comment: Please review the linked example, because your call to the ShellExecute function is missing a parameter (nShowCmd)...

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Even if there is another problem for which I will open another post, but shellexecute now works